# How do I get all node modules into the same directory?

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, node-modules, nvm

I'm using Mac OS. Most of my global npm modules are at `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/`. I installed `nvm` and now new global modules get placed in `/.nvm/versions/node/v15.5.1/lib`.

**What I Want To Know:**

1. Is there any problem with their being placed in `/.nvm/versions/node/v15.5.1/lib`, or is this what you'd expect once you install `nvm`?
2. Say I upgrade `node` to version `15.5.2`. Will any new global modules then go to `/.nvm/versions/node/v15.5.2/lib`? If so, will it be a problem that over time the global modules I add end up in different directories?
3. I'd like to remove all the modules from `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/` and reinstall in the new `nvm` directory to keep everything together. How should I approach this?

Answer (score 0):

1. No, this is expected.
2. `nvm install 15 --reinstall-packages-from=14` for example, would work for you.
3. `ls /usr/local/lib/node_modules | xargs npm i -g` will reinstall all your old modules in the new location. `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules` will remove the old ones. You can also run `nvm install node --reinstall-packages-from=node` for example (see [this section in the docs](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#migrating-global-packages-while-installing)).

Global modules in general are sometimes considered an antipattern, which is part of why `npx` was invented — so you don't have to deal with global modules getting stale and version issues with NVM and other version managers.